# Scripts menulet env issue

Tags: terminal, security, script

For many years, I have used the Scripts menulet (enabled from the preferences in Apple's **Script Editor**), which provides a little drop-down menu to trigger scripts -- not just AppleScripts, but shell scripts and, in my case, python3 scripts.

[image]

The scripts have worked flawlessly for years, but a while ago they stopped working, possibly in Ventura, possibly in Monterey. (I'm currently on Sonoma RC.) The scripts still work perfectly if called in the Terminal, or run from BBEdit, CodeRunner, etc, etc; but fail in the menulet.

I've discovered the root of the problem, but I'm wondering if anyone knows what its *cause* is, or why

If the script uses `env` to trigger python, e.g.:

`#!/usr/bin/env python3`

then it fails to run. As said, in the Terminal, `env` returns a valid python3, and the scripts run in all other environments.

If I change the first line to:

`#!/usr/local/bin/python3`

then it works.

I presume Apple has restricted or limited things 'for security' -- but bash scripts still work, so it's weird that I can't call `env`.

Any thoughts?